# Why is jest looking for a test file that no longer exists?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

While creating new tests, I got this error:

```
Determining test suites to run...Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/andrew/Documents/wise-fox/The-App/src/tests/components/AlertsComponent/AlertsPages/PromoPage3.test.js'
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:948:11)
    at Object.statSync (/home/andrew/Documents/wise-fox/The-App/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:297:22)
    at fileSize (/home/andrew/Documents/wise-fox/The-App/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/test_sequencer.js:71:73)
    at tests.sort (/home/andrew/Documents/wise-fox/The-App/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/test_sequencer.js:91:34)
    at Array.sort (native)
    at TestSequencer.sort (/home/andrew/Documents/wise-fox/The-App/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/test_sequencer.js:77:18)
    at /home/andrew/Documents/wise-fox/The-App/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/run_jest.js:148:26
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/home/andrew/Documents/wise-fox/The-App/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/run_jest.js:27:377)
    at /home/andrew/Documents/wise-fox/The-App/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/run_jest.js:27:537
```

The error is trying to look for a test file that no longer exists. I had copied a number of tests and then adapted the names of the files as well as the tests inside to fit the new files.

Previously, jest just realized that certain test files had disappeared (because of renaming), but in this case jest thinks these files still exist. I'm not sure why, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Framework: React 16
OS: Linux Elementary OS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, it had something to do with the obsolete snapshot files. I deleted them manually and the tests ran just fine

Comment: Really, it would help to *mention* where the snapshot files / directory typically are stored.

Answer (score 16):

For me it was not a snapshot issue, but a cache issue.
Run

```
jest --clearCache
```

to get rid of it.

Comment: Wow this was mean by jest... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just, delete the generated directory **snapshots** it will be generated where you have written YOUR_FILE_NAME.test.js.